# Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community with a previously expired license

Tags: windows-7, dreamspark, visual-studio-2015

I previously installed VS2013 Professional with a Dream Spark license (part of a Microsoft certification course).  I uninstalled it after the license ran out.

Now i tried to install VS2015 Community and a modal just says : License Prerelease Software: This license has expired. I never had a 2015 Community license i have no idea how it can be expired... And the only options given are to close VS or login to a Microsoft account (which does nothing). I cannot go to any of the menus (so no Help > Register). I tried going to the msdn license site but i couldnt find where to get a license. And several google searches have proved equally useless.

I also tried to repair my VS2015C and it failed saying there was an issue with .NET Fwk 4.6. I tried re-installing the 4.6 framework but after saying "all files downloaded successfully" it fails because some file is missing...

I believe this is unrelated but i used my one and only outlook account to login to each of these Visual Studios, and one at work, and various others but i assume these licences aren't linked in any way to my Microsoft account ?

Shouldn't i be allowed to install Community on my personal home computer ? If so how ? i'll get a work laptop soon with a Pro license but that's not the point ! My home computer is on Win7 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After failing to repair VS2015 Community multiple times, even with a verified iso, i did a full un-install and re-install and everything worked fine. I can now start VS and it was automatically licensed to my outlook account.